# Critical Path Method (CPM) algorithm

Tags: scheduling, critical-path

I am reading the book "*Planning and scheduling in manufacturing and services*" by M.Pinedo

I am a little bit confuse at the Critical Path Method (CPM) in this book. There is an example (4.2.3) on page 58:
Assume that we have 14 jobs with precedence constraints as in the below figure (in this example we use Job-on-node notion).
[image]

The duration of each job is given by:

[image]

where p_j is the duration (processing time) of job j.

For the forward procedure, the result which I calculate is the same as the book. (C_j' is the earliest possible completion time of job j)

[image]

However, for the backward procedure, everything is the same but one entry in column of job 5. The result for this column is 30 but I calculated the latest possible completion time of job 5 to be **26**.

[image]

(C_j'' is the latest possible completion time of job j)

May I ask how this result is 30?

---

**Update the algorithm**

I would like to add the algorithm for the backward procedure and my calculation step to clarify my question:

[image]

So according to this algorithm, job 5 has two successors which are job 8 and job 9.

Thus C_5''= min {S_8'',S_9''}

Where

- S_8'' = C_8'' - p_8 = 36 - 6 = 30
- S_9'' = C_9'' - p_9 = 36 - 10 = 26.

Then C_5''= min {30,26} = 26

Comment: Your result is correct. Books contain errors occasionally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### On the backward pass the latest possible completion time of job 5 is 26

You can see another example on the [PMI site - Understanding the basics of CPM calculations](https://www.pmi.org/learning/library/basics-cpm-scheduling-software-axon-8170)

- **Forward pass**: For the earliest possible completion time of a job, you take the **max** of the predecessors' end time. This is because it has to wait for the last predecessor to finish before it can start.
- **Backward pass**: For the latest possible completion time of a job, you take the **min** of the successors' start time. This is because only after it finishes, either (any) of the successors can start.

Answer (score 1):

Job 8 finishes at time 36 in the C_j'' table.  Job 8 takes 6 time units, so the latest job 5, job 8's predecessor, can finish is 36 - 6 = 30.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I just add the algorithm from the book and my calculation step for clarification. Since if I read the algorithm correctly the C_5'' should be 26.